# Aliases in R - function on load the R package

Tags: r

I'm building an R package and I want to set the aliases (alternative names) for some functions. I want to set them while loading a package. I tried with .onLoad
It looked like that :

```
.onAttach <- function(lib,pkg = "mypkg") {
  fun1a <- fun1
  fun2a <- fun2
}
```

but after building, installing and loading the package no aliases were visible.

Do you have idea how to solve a problem with aliases?

Comment: .onAttach is probably setting the variables in your package's environment. Why not just export the symbols in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: but then how should I set those alternative names and assign them to specific function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my utils package and it works to alias ln to log:

```
#' @export
ln <- log;
```

Comment: So it is just a line directly before log function code?

Comment: That's a roxygen2 tag to add `ln` to my `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: I exported my alias to NAMESPACE by hand (I know I shouldn't do that) and then in my actual function's code I added a line fun1a <- fun1 and then the function body but while building a package it still doesn't see fun1 object

Comment: If you put the line inside a function it will be local to the function; can you post your actual code?

Comment: `##' @export
gwaa2bigrr <- gwaa.to.bigrr
gwaa.to.bigrr <- function(formula, data, trait) {
  require(bigRR)}`

Comment: It looks like they are not in order; the alias should come after the declaration.